# Python: Loading a dictionary with numeric keys from a JSON string (with double quoted keys)

Tags: python, json

```py
>>> import json
>>> example = { 1: "banana", 2: "apple"}
>>> example
{1: 'banana', 2: 'apple'}
>>> json_example = json.dumps(example)
>>> json_example
'{"1": "banana", "2": "apple"}'
>>> from_str=json.loads(json_example)
>>> from_str
{'1': 'banana', '2': 'apple'}
```

My problem is quite simple, but I can't find a straightforward solution...

From a json encoded string (here `json_example`), where keys represent numeric values, but are double quoted (because JSON standard allows only double quoted string as property key), I want to load a dict where keys are numeric values.

But `json.loads` returns a dict where keys are strings. How can I get the keys as numeric values?

**EDIT:**

A one-liner like the one proposed by [@not_speshal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal) would be perfectly ok in most cases. But the context of this problem is a Django form (to read a json string provided by the user). I am looking for a solution which could involve a JSON decoder. So I can pass it as an argument to the Django `forms.JSONField` class, to avoid subclassing this class and writing a lot of Django-specific code.

Comment: `{int(k): from_str[k] for k in from_str}` ?

Comment: Convert them to numeric values after they've been read as strings. Pretty straightforward IMO, unless there's a reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: @not_speshal Sure it works, but I was looking for something more direct, like a JSON decoder... because my real use case is a little more complicated (need to use it in a Django form...). But maybe you're right and it's the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way I can think of is to go over the loaded dict and parse the `str` keys into `int`s like [@not_speshal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal) suggests in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037326/python-loading-a-dictionary-with-numeric-keys-from-a-json-string-with-double-q/68037607#comment120253721_68037326).

```
{int(k): from_str[k] for k in from_str}
```

---

You could use the `object_hook` argument to `json.loads()` if you wanted a single function call to do the trick. This doesn't save any computations because the object is *still* read as a `dict` with `str` keys that you then convert to `int`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load):

> `object_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded (a `dict`). The return value of `object_hook` will be used instead of the `dict`. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders (e.g. JSON-RPC class hinting).

```
example = { 1: "banana", 2: "apple"}
json_example = json.dumps(example)

def parse_int_keys(dct):
    rval = dict()
    for key, val in dct.items():
        try:
            # Convert the key to an integer
            int_key = int(key)
            # Assign value to the integer key in the new dict
            rval[int_key] = val
        except ValueError:
            # Couldn't convert key to an integer; Use original key
            rval[key] = val
    return rval

from_str = json.loads(json_example, object_hook=parse_int_keys)
# from_str is now 
# {1: 'banana', 2: 'apple'}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it also works on nested dicts without having to write any more code:

```
obj = {'a': 1, 'b': {1: 'abc'}, 0: [1, 2, 3], '1234': 'Hi!'}
json.loads(json.dumps(obj), object_hook=parse_int_keys)
# Output: 
# {'a': 1, 'b': {1: 'abc'}, 0: [1, 2, 3], 1234: 'Hi!'}
```

However, note that keys that were originally strings that can be parsed into integers (such as `'1234'` in my example above) will still be converted to integers because we have no way of distinguishing between the two cases.

Comment: Thanks! The solution with object_hook avoids me to write a lot of django code to create new form field type, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: And in fact, I do have nested dicts, so it is definitely the best approach in my case.

Comment: @scandel Great! If you could edit the actual motivation (don't want to write extra django code) into your question, I'll change my downvote to an upvote. It's always helpful to include why the easiest way is no good for you because then people can think of an answer that will actually help

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create an empty dict and fill it while iterating through the first one and cast the keys to int values?

Comment: Thanks, but not so straightforward... Longer than the one-liner provided by  @not_speshal in its comment.